# Date time conversion error in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

In my stored procedure, I am trying to pass parameters with this code

```
select @enddate = CONVERT(varchar, @days) + '-' + left(@P5, 4) + '20' + right(@P5, 2)
```

here `@enddate` datatype is `varchar(12)` and `@days` datatype is `int` and `@P5` datatype is `varchar(20)`

It is showing the below error

> *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string*

Any ideas on this?

thanks in advance

Comment: can you post parameters values you are using?

Comment: rs , i am passing @p5=2012-12-12 @days no need to pass because it is dynamic procedure

Comment: why are you trying to return `20122012` using left(@P5,4)+'20'+right(@P5,2)?

Comment: @sentil Somewhere in your code are you using `CONVERT(DATE, @enddate)` or `CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate)`?

Answer (score 0):

In trying to test this code out, I've not managed to trigger the same error you're seeing.

```
DECLARE @enddate AS VARCHAR(12) ,
    @days AS INT ,
    @P5 AS VARCHAR(20);

SELECT  @days = 5 ,
        @p5 = '2012-12-12';

SELECT  @enddate = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @days) + '-' + LEFT(@P5, 4) + '20' + RIGHT(@P5, 2);
PRINT @enddate;
```

produces the result

```
5-20122012
```

without an error.

You have suggested that this is part of a larger stored procedure. Either the data in your variables is not what you believe it to be or the error is elsewhere in your procedure.